# how to using Grep for remove the specific end word of line in perl?

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I will create a file every day , I want to remove the line that end character is utc and output to other file in perl,
I try to use grep an regexp,
but get the error msg as below,

```
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

the grep code :

```
system("grep -v \"utc$ \" /doc/$date/before > /doc/$date/after");
```

the file loos like

```
config setting
^MMon Nov 13 10:45:52.401 utc   -->the line is I wnat to remove
start configuration...
clock timezone utc 8
```

Any suggestions? I am more then happy to try anything at this point.

Comment: It's will get  "/doc/ is a directory , it's cannot get the variable $date

Comment: What are you trying to do?`What's must contain `$date` variable? where will this variable set? What's meaning of `"utc$ "`(sign dollar followed by space)?

Comment: How are your files, path named? Please post samples of path and maybe contents!

Comment: because I will create a file every day so that the date is a variable

Comment: path is /doc/$date/before , the $date is a variable

Comment: @georgetovrea  Updated my answer (at first I didn't realize you wanted a new file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is *no* need to go to external tools for such a common task. It involves starting a shell and yet another program, and (doubly) escaping things just right; it is error prone and far less efficient, and inferior in terms of error checking. Why not use Perl in a Perl program?

Read a file and write its lines over to a new file, skipping the ones you don't want. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40269154/4653379) for details, for example.

Here is a quick way using [Path::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Path-Tiny-0.104/lib/Path/Tiny.pm)

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Path::Tiny;

my $file     = '...';
my $new_file = '...';

my @new_lines = grep { not /utc\s*$/ } path($file)->lines; 

path($new_file)->spew(@new_lines);
```

The module's `path($file)` opens the file and `lines` returns the list of lines; they are filtered by `grep` and those that don't end in `utc` (with possible trailing space) are assigned to `@new_lines`.

Then the `spew` method writes those lines to `$new_file`.

For a couple of (other) ways to "edit" a file using this module see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46723567/4653379).

---

In a one-liner

```
perl -ne'print if not /utc\s*$/' file  > new_file
```

---

A direct answer may best illustrate (some of) the disadvantages of using external commands.

We need to pass to `grep`, via shell, particular sequences which would be interpreted by either or both Perl and shell; so they need be escaped correctly

```
system("grep -v 'utc\\s*\$' $old_file > $new_file");
```

This works on my system.

Comment: Your one liner would be better off with the `-p` flag  I think. `perl -pe 'next if m/utc$/' file` should do the trick.

Comment: @Sobrique Huh? What's the purpose of the `next` here? I thought `-p` _always_ prints the line and there's no way to prevent that. Am I wrong?

Comment: `-p` just inserts a `continue` block that prints `$_`.  That can be bypassed by loop control statements like `next`.

Comment: @Sobrique Doesn't work for me. And the [`continue` docs](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/continue.html) say _"Thus it can be used to increment a loop variable, even when the loop has been continued via the next statement"_. To me that sounds like the continue block is always executed.

Comment: Hmm, OK. I stand corrected. I'm getting muddled obviously. I'll go and review, because I'm at least _fairly_ sure there's a 'skip' option with `-p`. I'll go and try and figure out what it is.

Comment: @zdim,I have try to using you one-liner,but it's still cannot remove the line that the end is utc

Comment: @georgetovrea  huh ... are you sure it's `utc` at the end?  Any spaces or "funny" (non-printable) characters before the end?  Is this UNIX -- can you try `\z` instead of `$`?

Comment: @zdim,I have follow as you said , $ perl -ne'print if not /utc\z/' file > new_file , but it's still cannot remove the line , by the way ,I have update my question

Comment: @georgetovrea OK, let's try with some possible extra spaces: `/utc\s*$/`. (The shown file doesn't show whether there is anything _after_ `utc`; in your `grep` you have a space after `$`, which I don't know what to think of.)

Comment: @georgetovrea  There could also be a loose `\r` (carriage return) so also try `/utc[\r\s]*$/`

Comment: @zdim,  perl -ne'print if not /cst\s*$/' file > new_file work success, but I try to use grep in my perl, It's fail,     system("grep -v \"utc\s*$\" /file/$year/$datetime > /file/$year/new");       please can you help me ?

Comment: @georgetovrea  This is exactly the point of my post -- it is much harder to do it that way, and any such solution is much less reliable. If there is something you don't like in this post there is also a link to a very simple approach. (I updated the code to the optional space, `/utc\s*$/`.)

Comment: @georgetovrea  Having said that, I will add an attempt to fix your `grep` to the post shortly. I will let you know when I update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158823/discussion-between-georgetovrea-and-zdim).

Comment: @georgetovrea I have to go now, will be back in an hour and will update the post (and will let you know).  Then we can chat as well if you wish...

Comment: @georgetovrea  I added a direct answer to the end of my post.

Comment: @zdim,It's still cannot get I want, It's cannot work for me system("grep -Ev 'utc\\s*\$'  $file > $new");

Comment: @georgetovrea  That's another problem with running external commands out of Perl; there is no way for me to say why it works or not on your system.  I tested what I posted, with a file like yours and it works. (That runs out of a Perl script, right?)  But our systems and `grep`s may differ in many ways.  Why don't you just use Perl?  See that other post if anything here gives you trouble.

Comment: @georgetovrea  That last thing in my answer, `system(...)`, is supposed to be a line in a Perl script.  The `$old_file` and `$new_file` should be file names from your code.