# Fill in empty data before end of line

Tags: perl, pcre

I'm processing some CSV files. The last field is sometimes missing data, like so:
`first,last`
`John,Smith`
`Francis,`

This is causing ingestion errors when trying to load into a database. I'd like to add a space or some other 'filler' after the last comma, before the `crlf` but I'm having trouble filling this with a search/replace. I've tried the following for example:
`$data =~ s/,\x0d\x0a/,\x20\x0d\0xa/gi` but no space gets added before `crlf`.
Of course I need to keep the end of line so that rows are properly marked.

I've tried reading in with Path::Tiny as well as generic `open` but having no success so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: use a module to work with csv files, and a good one is [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV)

Now, for a job like this, this one time, a simple filter is OK:

```
my $line = q(first,last John,Smith Francis,);

$line =~ s/.*,\K$/filled_last_field/;
```

The greedy `.*` matches up to the *last* instance of the following pattern (comma here) on the line.
The [`\K` form](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.12.4/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) of the [positive lookbehind](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind)
 drops all previous matches so they are not consumed; so it only replaces the pattern after it (adds the phrase in this case, as needed).

If you'd like to first replace the file then you read it line by line and write the changed lines to a new file, which then gets moved over the old one.

```
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
open my $fh_out, '>', $new_file or die "Can't open $new_file: $!";

while (<$fh>) {
    print $fh_out s/.*,\K$/filled_last_field/r;
}
# Move $new_file to $file
```

where I've used the `/r` [modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers), which returns the modified string, just right for the `print` here. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46723567/4653379) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40269154/4653379) (for example) for full programs of this kind with relevant details.

Or, with [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny)

```
path($file)->edit_lines( sub { s/.*,\K$/ADDED/ } )
```

Methods to edit a file directly were added in the version 0.077. Many of the module's methods have their `_utf8` counterparts, and there is [edit_lines_utf8](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#edit_lines,-edit_lines_utf8,-edit_lines_raw) as well.

---

In a one-liner

```
perl -wpe's/.*,\K$/ADDED/' file.csv > new_file.csv
```

or, to change the input file *in-place*

```
perl -i -wpe's/.*,\K$/ADDED/' file.csv
```

or, to change it and also keep a backup

```
perl -i.bak -wpe's/.*,\K$/ADDED/' file.csv
```

Comment: Thanks -- I was not aware of the `\K` form at all. Whoever downvoted this care to explain?

Comment: Thanks @zdim; your reply was deleted for a time, so I thought it was deliberately erased. Glad to see it back. Also I'm working with UTF-16LE encoded data so I think Path::Tiny won't work as well here.

Comment: @sqldoug Don't know `-16LE` but many `Path::Tiny`'s methods have `_utf8` counterparts, `edit_lines` included.  Does that help?

Comment: Understood. I have not looked into `edit_lines`; I will check that out, thanks.

Comment: @sqldoug Thank you for the attribution.  Added a few bits

Comment: Thanks again @zdim. The \K form with the $ anchor solved it.